# Filter by field of Include object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I had this ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessesFilter( ProcessesFilterViewModel model)
    {
        IQueryable<Process> results = db.Processes
            .Include(s => s.Customers)

        if (model.Case>0)
        {
            result = result.Where(s => s.Case == model.Case);
        }

        if (model.CustomerID != null)
        {
            results = results
            .Where(s => s.Customers.CustomerID == model.CustomerID);<==== Doesnt Work
        }


        model.results = results.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

.Where(s => s.Customers.CustomerID == model.CustomerID);<==== Doesnt Work

How could it work?

Comment: Check out [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.110).aspx) method. e.g. `s => s.Customers.Any(c => c.CustomerID == model.CustomerID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Any`. For example:

```
if (model.CustomerID != null)
{
    results = results
        .Where(s => s.Customers.Any(c => c.CustomerID == model.CustomerID));
}
```